# how do you reference an array array in php from $_POST?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

```
<input type="checkbox" id="one" name="form[age[]]" value="1"/><label for="one">0 to 12 months</label>
```

How do I reference the `name` in PHP once it has been submitted using POST.  I am trying to collect all the checkbox values and then `implode age[]`, but I need to put this in a `form[]` for form validation.

When i `print_r[$_POST['form']['age']`, it displays `Notice: Undefined index: age`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `name="form[age][]"` for every checkbox with age value, and then after you send those values to PHP they will be available as an array $_POST['form']['age'].

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="form[age][]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="form[age][]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="form[age][]" value="3"/>
```

will result an array in PHP like:

```
$_POST['form']['age'][0]; // = 1
$_POST['form']['age'][1]; // = 2
$_POST['form']['age'][2]; // = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the key form and the key age in form:

```
$age = $_POST['form']['age'];
$imploded = implode(',', $age);
```

The value of the HTML-Attribute `name` is the key in $_POST, so `form` is `$_POST['form']`

**Edit:** The syntax of your name value is wrong, use `form[age][]` instead.

Comment: its not working. in that age[] only displays the last checked box. am i input the name= wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="one" name="form[age][]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="one" name="form[age][]" value="2"/>
.
.
<input type="checkbox" id="one" name="form[age][]" value="12"/>

<?
$implode = implode(',', $_POST['form']['age']);
?>
```